# Retrieving document from collection by id

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

My object I have in collection:

```
type Room struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId            `json:"Id"                  bson:"_id"`
    Name string                 `json:"Name"                bson:"name"`
}
```

Inserting into collection:

```
room = &Room{Id: bson.NewObjectId(), Name: "test"}
RoomCollection.Insert(room)
```

Retrieving from collection (any):

```
roomX := &Room{}
if err := RoomCollection.Find(bson.M{}).One(roomX); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("RoomX %s:\n%+v\n\n", roomX.Id, roomX)
```

This outputs:

```
RoomX ObjectIdHex("52024f457a7ea6334d000001"):
&{Id:ObjectIdHex("52024f457a7ea6334d000001") Name:test}
```

Retrieving from collection (by id):

```
roomZ := &Room{}
if err := RoomCollection.Find(bson.M{"_id": room.Id}).One(roomZ); err != nil {
    panic(err) // throws "not found"
}
```

This throws "not found" and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Your code looks correct. I just wonder if whitespace is the correct way to separate the json and bson field tags? Check with the MongoDB console and make sure Room.Id is stored with `_id` and not `id` as field name.

Comment: normally it's a comma

Comment: @tomwilde: Yes, but in the reflect package is says it is  `optionally space-separated` . Ondrej could try with single space instead of multiple.

Comment: You were right, it was the tab causing the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ahh, good to know. I added it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different key-value tags for a field should, according to the `reflect` package, be separated with space.

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

The `mgo`package fails to read the tag and stores the Id value as `id` instead of `_id`.